# Using bsearch with cstring, no results

Tags: c, search, binary-search, c-strings

I have no idea why this code don't work, what i did wrong?
It' for a university assignment, i need to use binary search to search a file with names. 

The result is always "Not found in the array", no matter what i try.

```
#define TAM 10
#define NUM 10

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b){
   return (strcmp(a, b));
}

void binary_search (char str[][TAM]){
    char * ptr_item;
    char searchkey[TAM];

    printf ("Enter a searchkey: ");
    scanf ("%s", &searchkey);

    ptr_item = (char*)
        bsearch (&searchkey,str,NUM, sizeof(char*), cmpfunc);

    if (ptr_item!=NULL)
        printf ("%s found in the array.\n",ptr_item);
    else
        printf ("%s not found in the array.\n",searchkey);
    return 0;
}
```

to add to the main function, i use this code for read the file, this bit works fine.

```
void read (char str[][TAM]){

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("Lista.txt", "r");

    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Arquivo não pode ser aberto!\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
        }

    char nome[TAM];

    for(int i=0; i<NUM;i++){
        fgets(str[i], TAM, file);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Here's a content of `Lista.txt`:

```
CHRISTIA 
EBONIE 
EMERSON
FLORIA
JOSEFINA
LAURO
MERRILEE
MILISSA
NANCY
RUTHAN
SHARAN
SHIRLEEN
TERI
```

Here's the code of main program:

```
int main(){
    char *str[NUM][TAM];
    read(str);
    binary_search (str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `char *str[NUM][TAM];` --> `char str[NUM][TAM];` 2) Basically `fgets` contains a newline in the input result. )

Comment: 3) `#define NUM 10` --> `#define NUM 13`

Comment: As i said above, the read function works, the str * was a test i did and forgot to clear all the pointers, the define doens't make a diference, the bsearch Always return a not found.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/VgA0Cu)

Comment: still, the return is "not found".

Comment: _FLORIA found in the array._ In DEMO. I think you are doing something wrong fix.

Comment: Call strspn after reading strings from both the file and the console, as is done in the example.

Comment: Post your actual code, not something you experiment with and forget to clean up. Use [edit] to fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
bsearch (&searchkey,str,NUM, sizeof(char*), cmpfunc);
//                           ------------- <--- wrong
```

Your array contains elements of type `char[TAM]`, not `char*`. **These types are not the same.**

```
fgets(str[i], TAM, file);
```

`fgets` doesn't strip the newline character from the end of the string, or any other whitespace.

```
scanf ("%s", &searchkey);
```

`scanf("%s",...)` won't read whitespace, including newline characters.